# Capture R output when running Rcmd.exe

Tags: r, installation, package

I have a line of code to capture the output of the version of `Java` installed:

```r
version <- system2("java","-version", stdout=TRUE)
```

However, if I include that line of code when creating a package in the `.onLoad` function, I run into a problem when building.

```r
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname){
  version <- system2("java","-version", stdout=TRUE)
  if(length(version)==0){
    stop("Missing version")
  }
}
```

Using the default RStudio "Clean and Rebuild", I can see both that the output is shown in the command line (the Java parts), and that the code then has the error showing the output was length 0:

> ==> Rcmd.exe INSTALL --preclean --no-multiarch --with-keep.source testpackage
>
> * installing to library 'C:/Users/JNolis2/Documents/R/win-library/3.5'
>
> * installing *source* package 'testpackage' ...
>
> ** R
>
> ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
>
> ** help
>
> *** installing help indices
>
> converting help for package 'testpackage'
>
> finding HTML links ...    hello                                   html
>
> done
>
> ** building package indices
>
> ** testing if installed package can be loaded
>
> java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)
>
> Error: package or namespace load failed for 'testpackage':
>
> .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'testpackage', details:
>
> call: fun(libname, pkgname)
>
> error: Missing version
>
> Error: loading failed
>
> Execution halted
>
> ERROR: loading failed
>
> - removing 'C:/Users/JNolis2/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/testpackage'
>
> In R CMD INSTALL
>
> Exited with status 1.

How can I ensure the output is captured even during this step?

Comment: Is that output going to `stderr` instead? `system2` has a way to capture that, too.

Comment: BTW: would it be a little safer to start your `.onLoad` with `if (!nzchar(Sys.which("java"))) stop("java not found")` or at least a `warning(...)`?

Comment: Yup @r2evans you're right, my issue was that it was being captured in stderr. I'm not sure if using Sys.which is more or less safe, I end up calling "java" with system2 later on in my code so I'm not sure if I should try to get as close as possible to that. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad it was `stderr` ... the recommendation to use `Sys.which` is mostly to protect you when it is used on other computers and mysterious errors pop up. This way, it fails early and load-and-clear on the problem. I think a `warning` might be more appropriate, to be honest, since (1) it is possible other functions are useful even without java installed, and (2) they might install java after starting R. I find it useful to "protect" myself from unintentionally-evil users/clients :-)